# Android Library on Bintray missing sources and javadoc

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, aar, bintray

I am trying to publish an Android library written in Kotlin as an AAR on Bintray to distribute it. I have already configured the whole project following various resources that I found online, and the publishing via `bintrayUpload` goes smoothly. [Here](https://github.com/MrAsterisco/RxFireAuth-Android/blob/master/rxfireauth/build.gradle.kts)'s my `build.gradle.kts`.

However, when I import the library in another project, I can reference all the classes correctly but:

- My library depends on RxJava 3, but that (and other dependencies) are not automatically downloading when importing my library in Gradle, resulting in Android Studio complaining about all the Rx classes.
- I can't see the sources and the JavaDoc.

On Bintray, everything looks normal: I can see two JAR files (`-Javadoc and` -sources`), one AAR, and the usual POM file. I've inspected all of them, and they contain everything I'm expecting, including the dependencies in the POM file.

You can inspect the full source code [here](https://github.com/MrAsterisco/RxFireAuth-Android) and the Bintray artifact [here](https://bintray.com/mrasterisco/RxFireAuth/rxfireauth/1.0.0#files/io%2Fgithub%2Fmrasterisco%2Frxfireauth%2F1.0.0).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `maven-publish` plugin. Sources were uploaded to maven repository but could not be downloaded together with `aar`. Sources were not included in `.module`.

I have found this plugin: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/xyz.tynn.android.sources - with this, sources are included in `.module` and are automatically downloaded together with `aar`.

This plugin doens't require any extra tasks for generating sources neither adding extra artifacts.

To use it all what has to be done is `apply plugin: "xyz.tynn.android.sources"`  and `publication` configured according to official Android documentation
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin

There is also plugin for `JavaDoc` https://github.com/tynn-xyz/BuildSrc/blob/master/README.md